# Outlook Desktop - Force account selection on new messages with mailto links

Tags: microsoft-outlook, windows-registry, mailto

Having multiple email accounts, it's often an issue sending a message from an undesired account.

Enabling the registry key `forceaccountselection` as [described here](https://admx.help/?Category=Office2016&Policy=outlk16.Office.Microsoft.Policies.Windows::L_ForceSelectionOfAccountBeforeSending), makes the "from" field empty on new compositions, forcing account selection, while preserving the account selection when replying. Nice and desired behavior as expected.

However, this only happens if the new message is initiated with the "New Email" button or `ctrl + N` from within the app. If in a web browser, clicking a `mailto:` link, Outlook does unfortunately pre-select an account.

For clarity, this is not about Outlook in the browser, but the Outlook Desktop window that opens `mailto:` links.

Running the latest version of Outlook for MS Office 365 on Windows 11. Has been tested on different websites on Firefox, Chrome and Edge.

Comment: Seems to be a recurring problem. People seem to use VBA scripts to always prompt for account selection/confirmation. An example can be found here https://www.howto-outlook.com/howto/check-sending-account-before-sending.htm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I also tried to add a mailto link to my inbound email, the result was same with yours: The registry key didn't work, I think it's a behavior by design.

However, you could add a warning by creating the following macro when sending a new email:

[image]

```
Private Sub Application_ItemSend(ByVal Item As Object, Cancel As Boolean)
Dim xPrompt As String
Dim xOkOrCancel As Integer
On Error Resume Next
xPrompt = "Warning: Please select the proper sending account before sending a message!"
xOkOrCancel = MsgBox(xPrompt, vbOKCancel)
If xOkOrCancel <> vbOK Then
    Cancel = True
End If
End Sub
```

If you select **OK**, this new email will be sent. If you select **Cancel**, after that, you could modify the info in this email.

More details about how to get a prompt or confirmation before sending emails in Outlook: **[How To Get A Prompt Or Confirmation Before Sending Emails In Outlook?](https://www.extendoffice.com/documents/outlook/5108-outlook-confirm-prompt-before-sending-email.html)**

Comment: Well, it's a workaround, but possibly also the only option at the moment. The mentioned guide doesn't mention signing the code, which may be necessary for the procedure to run after Outlook has been restarted. How to self-sign: https://www.howto-outlook.com/howto/selfcert.htm